# View background not drawn correctly

Tags: android, matrix

I'm trying to create a view that draws a background colour with an image on top of it. The image should be transformed by a matrix. The background should not be.

The `onDraw()` method looks like this:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), paint);

        Drawable drawable = getImageDrawable();

        if (drawable == null) {
            return;
        }

        int count = canvas.save();

        if (clipRect != null) {
            canvas.clipRect(clipRect);
        }
        canvas.concat(matrix);
        drawable.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restoreToCount(count);
    }
```

On some of the devices I've tested on, the background above and to the left of the image is not drawn correctly. See video here:
https://youtu.be/rno2XxaeNUA You'll need to pause the video to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was caused by accidentally overriding `View.getMatrix()`